# No output for Sqlite queries in Jupyter

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run this in Jupyter (here with dummy values):

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c = db.cursor()

QUERY = "select * from table limit 1"
c.execute(QUERY)
rows = c.fetchall()
```

Both cells execute, but I get no output, and this is the exact same syntax I've used to work with sqlite in Jupyter before. The same thing is happening with another notebook and another database that I've previously run queries on. Everything works smoothly in the command terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been an interaction with two installations of Python. Removed the second install and the queries work now.